# Set a view above navigation controller and below popupView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection View with navigation bar on StoryBoard. There is a popupView that appears when custom cell is selected.

On main StoryBoard I set a View `dimView` to make dark background color while pop up view is showing.

However when I test on device, dimView does not go above Navigation Bar or TabBar.

I tried following code `let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow! window.addSubview(dimView)`. But it makes dimView above pop up View.

I would like to set a view above navigation controller and below popupView.

Any idea how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the dimView on `navigationController.view`?

Comment: I tried it but it hides all the view including popupView.

Answer (score 0):

Have You try adding dimview on window but below popUp like this

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
window.insertSubview(dimView, belowSubview: popupView)
```

Comment: I have implemented the code,  but it hides all the view including popupView.